# why there is a memory error while I push a object which contain a critical_section?

Tags: c++, stl, critical-section

```
class Wrap
{
  CRITICAL_SECTION cs_;
public:
  Wrap() { InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  ~Wrap() { DeteteCriticalSection(&cs_); }
  Wrap & operator=(const Wrap& rhs) { return *this; }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<Wrap> v;
  v.push_back(Wrap());   //Memory error.
}
```

Please tell me what lead the error and how can I fix it.

Comment: Please add the full details of the error you're getting.

Comment: ["A critical section object cannot be moved or copied."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683472.aspx)

Comment: A normal memory error " this memory can not be read."

Answer (score 1):

James was right in his comment. Try this:

```
class Wrap
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION cs_;
public:
    Wrap()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_);
    }

    Wrap(const Wrap&)
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&cs_);
    }

    ~Wrap()
    {
        DeleteCriticalSection(&cs_);
    }   
};
```

Such things can be easily detected with AppVerifier from Debugging tool for windows.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much! It works. I forget to make sure the copy constructor has correct behavior.

Comment: Actually you should also take care about `operator=` (and OP did have it). The requirement for element in most STL collections is both copy-constructible and assignable. Assignment will not be used in push_back nor in reallocations, but is needed for `*iteraotr = value` or `collection[i] = value` and some algorithms, for example sort.